# Не могу изменить значение progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

```
private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pb1.Minimum = 0;
            pb1.Maximum = 100;
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 100;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            pb1.Value = 50; // 50 для теста вообще Value++;
        }
```

Не работает и не меняет, работаю в Blend VS. 2 часа сидел гуглил не знаю что делать. Сама программа запускается без проблем. Не работает только прогресс бар.

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("123");
        }
```

Причем если так, MSGBox работает, а если выше добавить

```
pb1.Value = 50;
```

то уже не вызывается msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каком потоке вызывается событие? Пробовали через диспетчер вызывать?

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        pb1.Value = 50;
    });     
}
```

Или, как вариант, юзать [dispatcher timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)